# VS2019: Project B references Project A and VS and Project B throws "Could not load file or assembly" on one of the assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have two Projects, Project A and Project B.

Project B references Project A and Project A references Assembly X. Assembly X references Assembly Y. Therefore the dependency chain is `Project A -> Project B -> Assembly X -> Assembly Y`

When I build Project B and launch via. debugger, it launches fine. Assembly X and Y are both loaded.

However, when I launch Project A, Project B and Assembly X are both loaded, but Assembly Y is not.

How do I resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: In witch. Net version your projects are?

Comment: .NET version4.7.2 @ilyes